# How to hide misplaced posts on a Yammer group using a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, yammer

I have a Yammer group that is being lightly spammed with off-topic posts, and I am trying to put together a chrome extension to filter them out.  The posts all begin like so:

```
<li class="yj-thread-list-item" data-thread-id="575529285222400" data-qaid="thread">
<div data-message-id="575529285222400" class="indicators-treatment yj-message-list-item yj-thread-starter is-not-translated">
<div class="yj-message-list-item--message-container yj-message-container">
<div class="yj-message-accessibility-header">
<h3 class="yj-acc-hidden">
<span class="yj-message-accessibility-header--byline" id="e89">


    Offending Text
</span>
```

My content.js currently looks like this:

```
var misplacedPost = document.getElementsByClassName('yj-message-accessibility-header-byline').innerHTML = "Offending Text";


if (misplacedPost) {
  misplacedPost.parentnode.removeChild(misplacedPost)
}
```

If the post contains the offending text in the header, I want to remove the beginning <li class> but I'm not sure if parentnode.removeChild is the right method?  Am I on the right track?